# datetime index to datetime series not working in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, indexing

I am trying to convert a datetime index to a datetime series but I get an error:

```
ticks = pd.date_range(start = '2019-12-30', end = '2020-02-11', periods = 6)
ticks.to_datetime()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-f41607e594d5> in <module>
----> 1 ticks.to_datetime(dayfirst=False)

AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'
```

Why and what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `ticks` are already `DatetimeIndex`, so no convert necessary:

```
ticks = pd.date_range(start = '2019-12-30', end = '2020-02-11', periods = 6)
```

If want `Series`:

```
s = ticks.to_series()
```

Or:

```
s = pd.Series(ticks)
```

---

If want convert to datetimes, is it possible by [`pandas.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
pd.to_datetime(ticks)
```